# Postgresql 11 SSPI authentication failing

Tags: postgresql, authentication

On windows 2016 in AD setup when I try to use SSPI with postgresql 11 and following settings :

pg_hba.conf:

```
host    all all 127.0.0.1/32    sspi    map=newmap #IP4
```

pg_ident.conf:

```
newmap  SrvSupportPsgr  srvsupportpsgr
```

log:

> Log: no match in usermap "newmap" for user "SrvSupportPsgr" authenticated as "SrvSupportPsgr@domainname"
>
> FATAL: SSPI authentication failed for user "SrvSupportPsgr"

this account has superuser on postgres and local admin + domain user on AD.
I have tried putting usernames in double quotes as well.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are authenticated as "SrvSupportPsgr@domainname", then that is what needs to be in the 2nd column of pg_ident.conf; including the "@domainname" part.  (Or it could be a regexp which matches to that)

Also, pg_ident.conf is case sensitive.  In the third column, "SrvSupportPsgr" is not the same thing as "srvsupportpsgr".

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried with domainname part added but didn't work. DB username is all lower case.

Comment: The error message is showing the attempted username as mixed case.

Comment: but isn't it suppose to map it to lowercase provided. thanks

Comment: Mapping to lower case for unquoted SQL identifiers is done inside the database.  You are not inside the database until after the connection is established, you are outside of it.  (And if it did map to lower case, I think the error message would have reflected that.)